# How do I build up mathematical intuition?

Tags: soft-question, education

I will be a freshman in high school next fall. Recently I felt like my math skills were bad. I can hardly figure out what to do in problems, and if I try and look at it from a different angle it feels so difficult. How do I deal with trying to build up math logic?

Comment: I recommend learning how to derive all the formulas from scratch. And don't just look up the explanation of how to derive the formula. Try to figure it out for yourself first. If you get stuck, read just enough of the explanation to get unstuck, then try to finish the rest of it yourself.

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of thinking of mathematics as a bunch of rules to be memorized and applied by rote processes. Don't just memorize what a rule is, but rather learn why it is true. Don't memorize What Rule to Apply in this situation, but rather learn why does that rule apply here, and how does it move you towards a solution.

Comment: Hmm, I suggest reading [Language, Proof and Logic](https://homepages.uc.edu/~martinj/Symbolic_Logic/341%20Syllabus,%20Textbook,%20Handouts,%20Notes/LPL%20textbook.pdf) and [How to Prove It](https://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-Structured-Approach-2nd/dp/0521675995).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Garner Mathematical Intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459589/how-to-garner-mathematical-intuition)

Answer (score 1):

I'm only a recent math major as a college freshman myself, but I can offer you a second-hand book recommendation that's helped my friends tremendously, some of whom have gone on to excel in math competitions such as the IMO: AoPS' contest preparation textbooks at https://artofproblemsolving.com/store