# Any mathematic book to build intuition and logic?

Tags: soft-question, intuition, book-recommendation

I'm a 14 year old 8th grader in the USA. I always had a interest in math when I was younger but I wanted to become good at it. I have been searching about how to become good at math and I stumbled across a few key points such as inituition and logic. I was confused about how to apply those takeaway since I was so used to what my school taught me to do. I want to be able to use both logic and intuition to be successful in the physics department in the future and to generally become a better mathematician.

Comment: Related by OP [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098378/how-to-get-better-at-building-logic-and-ideas-in-math), building intuition [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4106504/how-do-i-build-up-mathematical-intuition)

Answer (score 1):

Nice to hear!

A key idea of becoming better at math and science is to think of logical reasoning as a skill. Any skill, like learning how to play a piano, takes time and lots of good practicing. Intuition on problem solving comes from doing lots of problems. A mechanic can diagnose a car by listening to it because they have worked on LOTS of cars. So having intuition on problem solving comes from working on lots of problems. You will be able to look at problem and use your past experience and knowledge on how to attack the problem.

To work towards your goal I would simply go to a library or look up free online courses on algebra and trigonometry. These two are the building blocks of classical physics (I had to take classical physics I and II for my program in college). Then after that you could look into pre-calc texts, then go into calculus texts.

I personally like reading the text, understand the examples, and solving problems at the end of the chapter. If I don't understand a concept I would ask on here or just look up a video on YouTube.

Never be discouraged if things get complicated. Everything can be broken into bite size pieces and always remember what your goal is in the end. I feel like math and science is one of the most rewarding skills to have and makes you a more valuable person because of your analytic skills.

Best of luck on your journey!